# AWS Amplify in React, how can I render the new data from the subscribed listener

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

I am developing a React project & using AWS Amplify as a tool for serverless backend, in which I have a DynamoDB as my database in AWS Cloud.

My React app needs to detect realtime data update in DynamoDB. I am using GraphQL API from Amplify.

The GraphQL API generated by Amplify provides a `subscriptions` API for subscribing for data changes in real-time. I think that's exactly what I need, so I am using it:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState, useRef} from 'react';
import Amplify, { API, graphqlOperation } from 'aws-amplify';
import { onCreateData } from './graphql/subscriptions';

// subscribe to listen to new data creation in DynamoDB
const subscription = API.graphql(
    graphqlOperation(onCreateData)
).subscribe({
    next: (newData) => {
      // New data is received here outside 'App' functional component,
      // how can I render the data then?
      console.log(`new data: ${JSON.stringify(newData)}`);
      
    }
});

// I can't put the above subscription code inside App component, I don't know why but it just doesn't work unless I move it outside the App functional component.

function App() {
  const [dataArray, setDataArray] = useState([]);
   ...

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchDataArray();
    showDataArray();
    return () => {
      //cleanup
    }
  }, [dataArra])

  return (<div>
    <canvas ref={canvasRef}/>
  </div>)
}

export default App;
```

Problem is the `subscription` for new data insertion in DynamoDB only work if I put it outside the `function App(){...}` as you can see above. So, when `newData` is received in the subscription callback `next: (newData)`, how can I show the new data in `App` component?

You can see inside my `App` component I have state variable `dataArray`, the ideal solution is to update this `dataArray` state with `newData` but I think it is impossible now. So, in general I wonder how can I show the new data in my `App` component now?

P.S. [Amplify GraphQL API doc sample code](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/graphqlapi/getting-started/q/platform/js#enable-queries-mutations-and-subscriptions) (if you see the "subscription" section) also shows that the subscription code is in the same level as imports.

Comment: follow some tutorial?  react FC (your App is a FC, you can convert it into class component) requires a hook form like `useSubscription` - https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/subscriptions/

Comment: I would like to know how to subscribe in my functional component, not class component. Whether it is possible.

Comment: did you try to add it with a useEffect hook inside App?

Answer (score 5):

We use amplify for our projects and one example we have is for a simple chat function below:

```
interface ChatMessagesProps {
  internal?: boolean
  convoId: string
}

export const ChatMessages: FC<ChatMessagesProps> = ({ internal, convoId }) => {
  const classes = useStyles()
  const {
    appState: { user }
  } = useAppState()

  let [messages, setMessages] = useState<any>([])
  let [currentConversationId, setConversationId] = useState<string>(convoId)
  const listRef = useRef<VariableSizeProps>()

  let subscription = useRef<ISubscriptionObject | null>(null)
  let updateSubscription = useRef<ISubscriptionObject | null>(null)

  const addNewMessage = ({ onCreateMessage }) => {
    console.log(onCreateMessage)
    // from here we can do whatever we want with the data within the context of this component
  }

  const messageUpdated = ({ onUpdateMessage }) => {
    console.log(onUpdateMessage)
    // from here we can do whatever we want with the data within the context of this component
  }

  const getConversationDetails = async () => {
    subscription.current = graphQLSubscription(
      onCreateMessage,
      { conversationId: currentConversationId },
      addNewMessage
    )

    updateSubscription.current = graphQLSubscription(
      onUpdateMessage,
      { conversationId: currentConversationId },
      messageUpdated
    )
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (currentConversationId) {
      getConversationDetails()
    }
    return () => {
      subscription?.current?.unsubscribe()
      updateSubscription?.current?.unsubscribe()
    }
  }, [currentConversationId])

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <MessageList listRef={listRef} messages={messages} internal={internal} />
      <MessageInput userId={user?.id || ''} internal={internal} conversationId={currentConversationId} />
    </div>
  )
}

const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  root: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    position: 'relative'
  }
}))
```

And we use the helper `graphQLSubscription`

```
export const graphQLSubscription = (subscription: string, options: any, callback: (d: any) => void) => {
  return API.graphql(graphqlOperation(subscription, options)).subscribe({
    next: ({ value: { data, errors } }) => {
      console.log(errors)
      callback(data)
    }
  })
}
```

For your example code you would just want to store you subscription in a ref in order to be able to unsubscribe on unmount as well

```
import React, {useEffect, useState, useRef} from 'react';
import Amplify, { API, graphqlOperation } from 'aws-amplify';
import { onCreateData } from './graphql/subscriptions';

function App() {
  const [dataArray, setDataArray] = useState([]);
  const subscriptionRef = useRef()
   ...

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchDataArray();
    showDataArray();

    subscriptionRef.current = API.graphql(
      graphqlOperation(onCreateData)
    ).subscribe({
      next: (newData) => {
        // New data is received here outside 'App' functional component,
        // how can I render the data then?
        console.log(`new data: ${JSON.stringify(newData)}`);
      }
    });

    return () => {
      //cleanup
      subscriptionRef.current.unsubscribe()
    }
  }, [dataArra])

  return (<div>
    <canvas ref={canvasRef}/>
  </div>)
}

export default App;
```

From there you can extract it into helper functions within the component or within you project like above

Comment: I'm struggling with typing the subscription Ref - can you drop where you found/how you wrote ISubscriptionObject? Thanks!